# Nested def edit undefined method error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

I have three models with relationships: `Forum`, `Topic` and `Post`. I want to edit `Post`.

This is Post_controller:

```
def update
  @forum = Forum.find params[:forum_id]
  @topic = Topic.find params[:topic_id]
  @post = @topic.posts.find(params[:id])
  if @post.update(post_params)
    redirect_to forum_topic_path(@forum.id, @topic.id)
  end
end

def edit
  @forum = Forum.find params[:forum_id]
  @topic = Topic.find params[:topic_id]
  @post = Post.find(params[:id])
end
```

This is edit.html.slim:

```
= simple_form_for ([@forum, @topics, @topics.posts.build]) do |f|
  div.new_message
    p 
        b Ответ в тему  
    = f.label 'Текст сообщения:'
    = f.text_area :content,rows: '15', cols: '82' 
    div.forum_button
      = f.submit 'Изменить'
```

This is the error:

```
NoMethodError in Posts#edit

undefined method `posts' for nil:NilClass
```

Comment: Show your controller action for `edit`? Perhaps, you want to use `@topic.posts.build` instead of `@topics.posts.build`.

Comment: That's why you are getting that error. You are using `@topics.posts.build` in your view, you have to define `@topics` in your `edit` action in the controller. Or, as you have `topic` defines, you should use that in your view.

Comment: Try my answer and let me know if that works.

Comment: work. big thx. wwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwww

Comment: Awesome! You're most welcome :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The instance variable is defined as `@topic` but **NOT** `@topics` in your controller's `edit` action.
That's why you get the mentioned error when you call: `@topics.posts.build`.

You should use `@topic` instead of `@topics` in your view:

```
= simple_form_for ([@forum, @topic, @topic.posts.build]) do |f|
```

Answer (score 0):

**You need to fix two places:**

Replace @topics word for @topic

```
= simple_form_for ([@forum, @topic, @topic.posts.build]) do |f|
  div.new_message
    p 
        b Ответ в тему  
    = f.label 'Текст сообщения:'
    = f.text_area :content,rows: '15', cols: '82' 
    div.forum_button
      = f.submit 'Изменить'
```

**Hope this helps!**